# Embed an macro to Excel 2007 xml

Tags: asp.net, xml, macros, c#-3.0, visual-studio-macros

Anyone know if you can embed a macro in an xml file?

I have an xml file that I create with a .net web application and it opens
with Excel 2007, but would be nice to attach a macro to it as well.
I want to attach a macro to this xml file programmatically. So that when I open this xml file in Excel 2007 than the macro runs automatically

Thanks.

Comment: Are you producing Excel 2003, 2007, .. ?

Comment: The xml file is opened as Excel 2007.

Comment: Are you talking about a .xml file or a .xlsx file?

Comment: I am talking about .xml file which opens in Excel 2007 and I want to attach a macro to this .xml file

Comment: Might be a good idea to show us (some of) your code and the xml you're actually producing. The above answer could still mean you produce Excel readable xml in a 2003 version, or in a 2007/2010 version.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot embed a macro in an Excel 2007 XML file.  It isn't supported.  You also cannot embed a macro in an xlsx file, security requirements prohibit it.

To embed a macro you have to use a xlsm file.  Howerever, even though most of xlsm is text wrapped in a zip, the macro project itself is a binary file.